# Adding an AMPscript to a block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have created an email with "buttons" (graphics) in Marketing Cloud.  I want to attach an AMPscript to the button so that when a recipient "clicks" on the button a PDF opens.
I can see the HTML code for the button in HTML Editor and see a drop down for AMPscript formatting with a dropdown of various commands, e.g., Concat, Format, etc, but am unable to utilize them and add the AMPscript.

Any ideas how/where I would be able to add the AMPscript so that a specified PDF would open when the "button" is selected?

Comment: That's not the way that AMPScript works.  Unlike, client-side JavaScript, AMPScript is rendered before the content is displayed.

Comment: No AMPscript is required for what you've described, unless the PDF URL is calculated.